# How do I create slippery and light jelly for drinking?

Tags: gelatin, jelly

I created an experiment with 10 different water/gelatin ratios but none provided the required results.

I'd like to create viscosity similar to Jelly Juice pouch bags. However, when the results I'm getting are thick liquid (gelatine like thickening agent) or too heavy jellly to consume (probably ok eaten by a spoon, but not when sucked via pouch bag).

So my guess, is the retail jelly pouch contents are broken apart and are mixed with a different liquid to make them slide out of the pouch easier. But my jelly bits still feel heavy.

Is there a recipe to make a lighter, more slippery jelly that stays together when jellified but is easy to break apart when consumed?

Comment: Are you fixed in using gelatin or can or want you to use other thickening agents as well? Perhaps you should extend your experiments to these agents as well. I am not used to thickened drinks but I  think carrageen or pectin is much more common

Comment: There's Agar Agar too, but it tends to be stiffer than gelatine, when made into a jelly.  I've never tried to make a drink with though.  Other the other end, you could use egg-yolks to make a custard-like texture.

Comment: The "jelly juice" brand pouches I'm seeing on Amazon are vegan... they use something called gellan gum as a thickener but I don't know how accessible it is for a home cook or even whether the product I found is the one you're talking about. Regardless, starting with the correct thickener, if possible, is probably the first step - read the package.

Comment: Xanthan gum thickens well too.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking to create a juice/drink which has jelly bits floating inside, or are you looking to make a container of jelly that when broken and mixed around, becomes a drinkable part liquid, part jelly?

Comment: @Diu.Lei the second once (sorry for late reply)

Answer (score -1):

Try playing with pectin. I would say 10-15g per L +-. Needs Sugar and Acid to activate, which is ideal in a drink

Gelatin is animal based. Pectin is fruit based

Comment: Pectin does not produce a slippery texture, though, on the contrary, it is stickier than many other thickeners.